# Dynamic SQL without sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title of this question is probably not entirely accurate for what I'm asking, but I'm really not sure how else to summarize it in a single sentence. But the core of it is that I'm looking for some way to handle input that can be either specific values, a select statement or a blank string without sp_executesql. I'm writing reports for a system that allows custom sql but passes parameters in an odd way. What you normally are supposed to do is configure parts of your where clause in the application, which then gets mapped to a token ie: #property#

When the report is run the vendor's system takes your sql statements and, if the user has selected a value for the parameter mapped to that token, inserts it into your sql before running it. Coming from a reporting background where we controlled our own user interface application this drives me nuts because the code is scattered all over, and there are lines of invalid sql littered all throughout the report definitions that I have to replace every time I'm debugging something. I'm trying to clean this up and move all of the token assignments to the top of my code where I dump them into variables that I'll use through the rest of the query. For example, the report configuration in the application sets Condition50 = v.primaryKey in (#vendor#).
Then whenever a query filters on vendors it looks like this.

```
WHERE 1=1
#Condition50# --at runtime, #Condition50# is replaced with AND v.primaryKey in (#vendor#)
```

My problem is that some of the tokens the system generates are passed through in different formats based on how a user picked their parameter values. For example if a user explicitly picked a few properties then the app replaces my #property# token with a value like: 1,2,3 (representing the primary keys of the properties, most filters seem to work this way). That means I can wrap that token in single quotes and make it into a comma separated list that I can use CHARINDEX on to filter with. ie for approvers:

```
WHERE (1 = 1)
AND (
    @selectedApprovers = ',,' OR
    CHARINDEX(',' + cast(x.approverhmy as varchar) + ',', @selectedApprovers, 0) > 0
)
```

In the case of properties a user can also select a grouping of properties (a property list). When a user does this the #property# token gets replaced with a select statement that looks like this: `select hProperty from listprop2 where hPropList in (1,2,3)`. I don't have access to sp_executesql so I can't just dump the filter into a varchar, detect when a list of specific ids is provided and use that to generate valid sql to populate a table variable. If I set up such a table (as below) and the user doesn't pick a list then the SQL becomes invalid:

SQL in file

```
DECLARE @selectedProperties TABLE (hMy numeric)
IF '#hProp#' <> ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @selectedProperties
    #hProp#
END
```

becomes - with specific properties

```
DECLARE @selectedProperties TABLE (hMy numeric)
IF '#hProp#' <> ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @selectedProperties
    1,2,3
END
```

becomes - with a property list selected

```
DECLARE @selectedProperties TABLE (hMy numeric)
IF '#hProp#' <> ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @selectedProperties
    select hProperty from listprop2 where hPropList in (1,2,3)
END
```

or, if no properties are selected

```
DECLARE @selectedProperties TABLE (hMy numeric)
IF '#hProp#' <> ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @selectedProperties
    --error, invalid sql
END
```

I'm getting the creeping suspicion that for this one filter type I'm going to have to suck it up and live with the weird behavior, and continue littering the where clauses in my SQL with #property# tokens. I'm hoping someone will have an idea for an oddball trick I can use to handle both of these scenarios without causing SQL parsing errors. I really wish I could change some of the design decisions in the app we're using.

Comment: This really seems like the application is the problem here. I would suggest tagging that, and perhaps someone with experience with that application can help you. To me, however, an application replacing something like `#Condition50#` with a clause for your `WHERE`, or even an entire `WHERE` sounds terrifying. If the developer of your application hasn't been **extremely** careful, it could be very open to injection.

Comment: Hah, ever since I started this job I've been recoiling in horror every time I learned more about this app but we're kind of stuck with it. The entire business relies on it and the vendor basically has a monopoly on the market. As much as I'd like to burn it to the ground and switch to something else or build something sane, we'd lose too many millions of dollars in the meantime. Just be glad I didn't tell you anything about the data model, if you saw how the tables were designed and linked together you'd claw your eyes out. For now the best I can do is limit how much the insanity affects us.